# Какой командой можно увидеть все созданные артефакты в докер контейнере при docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

у меня есть 1 stageый контейнер который собирает nginx и lua из исходников, мне необходимо реализовать multistage, где в 1 stage будет происходить сборка, а во 2 stage запуск. Как можно увидеть все созданные артефакты в 1 stage?

```
# get image from...
FROM debian:9 as builder
# maintainer
    LABEL maintainer="paffin"
#main dir
    WORKDIR /usr/local/src/
#Env versions
    ENV nginx_v="1.19.8" LuaJIT_v="2.0.5" ngx_v="0.3.0" lua_v="0.10.9rc7"
# updates
    RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y wget build-essential libpcre3 libpcre3-dev zlib1g zlib1g-dev
# modules
    RUN wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${nginx_v}.tar.gz && tar -zxvf nginx-${nginx_v}.tar.gz
    RUN wget http://luajit.org/download/LuaJIT-${LuaJIT_v}.tar.gz && tar -zxvf LuaJIT-${LuaJIT_v}.tar.gz
    RUN wget https://github.com/simpl/ngx_devel_kit/archive/v${ngx_v}.tar.gz && tar -zxvf v${ngx_v}.tar.gz 
    RUN wget https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module/archive/v${lua_v}.tar.gz  && tar -zxvf v${lua_v}.tar.gz

    RUN cd LuaJIT-${LuaJIT_v} && make -j2 && make install
    RUN cd nginx-${nginx_v} && export LUAJIT_LIB=/usr/local/lib && export LUAJIT_INC=/usr/local/LuaJIT/include/luajit-2.0 
    RUN cd nginx-${nginx_v} && ./configure --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
    --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
    --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
    --user=nobody --group=nogroup \
    --prefix=/usr/local/nginx \
    --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib' \
    --add-module=/usr/local/src/lua-nginx-module-${lua_v} \
    --add-module=/usr/local/src/ngx_devel_kit-${ngx_v}
    RUN cd nginx-${nginx_v} && make && make install

FROM debian:9-slim
WORKDIR /usr/local
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/nginx  ./
    EXPOSE 80 22 443
    CMD [ "nginx", "-g", "daemon off;" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Собрать образ этапа сборки builder:

```
docker build -f Dockerfile --target builder -t test-builder
```

Затем создать контейнер из этого образа:

```
docker run --rm -it test-builder bash
```

Внутри контейнера можно будет посмотреть все артефакты этапа builder.
Подробнее здесь [Stop at a specific build stage](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#stop-at-a-specific-build-stage)